Trouble with Youtube API regarding search relevance
The Youtube API is not returning relevant videos or even close to top results for most queries and is instead returning videos that are either irrelevant with high views or relevant with less than 100 views.
I'm currently running the following code:
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=google_api_key)


class VideoUrls:
    def __init__(self, name, url):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url

    def __str__(self):
        return f"\nname of video: {self.name}\nurl: {self.url}"


def youtube_request(query, results):
    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        type="video",
        maxResults=results,
        q=query,
        order="relevance",
    )
    response = request.execute()

    instances = {}
    for i in range(results):
        name = response['items'][i]['snippet']['title']
        url = response['items'][i]['id']['videoId']
        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={url}"
        instances[name] = VideoUrls(name, url)

    return instances


videos = youtube_request("Cherry wine hozier", 5)
for video in videos.values():
    print(video)

This is returning a list of videos as expected but these videos are not relevant to the query. Searching for some songs will return random popular videos or, as in the above code, will return covers of the song with less than 100 views. How can I fix the fact that the youtube api is not giving me the top results? I've tried order="viewCount" as well, but it just reorders the same videos by views instead of providing new videos with more views.

Does web-scraping YouTube UI search results help? See https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=Cherry%20wine%20hozier&order=relevance and its source code: https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/4557d9aef14a528a805baf474ba5f4ec27de9f03/search.php#L116-L257

I have tried the Youtube Data API as mentioned int the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list and tried their search API tool in the page and resulted as per your requirements. have a look at the page and try there
